# Is it possible to install Jenkins on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, jenkins

I managed to overcome the error message as was described in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66230916/2875641 but yet, the Jenkins service cannot start.
Us it possible to start it on Win 10 Home at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this article as a workaround or purchase a license for Windows Pro (the easiest solution by far). You can see from the article and below that getting Pro is just simply easier.

[Jenkins on Windows Home](https://medium.com/swlh/jenkins-devkit-windows-home-231aef40c415)

> Required Tools You will need the following tools to for this solution
> Virtualbox: this is an free open source solution that will allow you
> to run virtual machines on Windows 10 Home. Docker Toolbox: all the
> tools you will need to run Docker with Virtualbox on Windows 10 Home.
> Chocolatey (optional): package manager that can facilitate downloading
> and installing packages on Windows. Using Chocolatey (Optional)
>
> Step 1: Creating Virtual Machine We need to create a virtual machine
> running Linux that will host the Docker Service. docker-machine create
> --driver virtualbox default Note, we are calling our system default, but you can use another name of your choosing. Step 2: Reconfigure the
> Docker Service Docker Machine does not have an option to run without
> TLS, so we have to reconfigure the service on the virtual machine.
>
> First log into the virtual machine: docker-machine ssh default Inside
> the system, run these commands to edit the configuration and restart
> the Docker service:

sudo sed -Ei 
"s/(DOCKER_HOST='.*:)(.*)/\12375'/" 
/var/lib/boot2docker/profile
sudo sed -i 
"s/DOCKER_TLS=auto/DOCKER_TLS=no/" 
/var/lib/boot2docker/profile
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart

> Exit out of the virtual machine with CTRL-D or by typing exit.

The next steps are setting it up once installed.

> Step 0: Create Project Structure and files Run these PowerShell
> commands step by step below to create the directory and file structure
> for the project.